# Unittest immutable object variables?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class

I am having issues changing object variables within class method. Example:

```
import unittest

class Example(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.var_A = "foo"

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.var_A, "foo")
        self.var_A = "bar"

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.var_A, "bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**test_2** fails as `self.var_A` value has not been changed to "bar" in **test_1**

If I try to place it outside `setUp` and change it via `self.__class__.var_A` , it works.
Working example:

```
import unittest

class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    var_A = "foo"

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.var_A, "foo")
        self.__class__.var_A = "bar"

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.var_A, "bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Question:** Why is the second example working and the first isn't?
It is confusing because it appears `self.var_A` is immutable and can not be changed after **setUp**, but I can use it as a part of the object within other test methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test runner will execute the `setUp()` method for each test method, so attributes defined in `setUp()` are reset each time. That's intentional and documented FWIW - you don't want your tests to depend on each other.

Class attributes on the other hand are left alone, which is why your second example "works".

Note that there's also a `setUpClass` method that is only executed once for all tests in the testcase, but you should only use it for attributes that are 1/ read-only and 2/ costly to set up. Once again, your tests should NOT depend on side-effects from other tests, each test MUST work in isolation, and each test must work whatever other tests from the same testcase have been (or not) executed before.

Comment: "The setUp() and tearDown() methods allow you to define instructions that will be executed before and after each test method." ~ right from unittest docs. I have read this but it appears my brain did not register the information :)  Thank you for brief and to the point explanation. Have a great day